# add unlimited input fields with prototype

Tags: javascript, html, prototype

i am adding unlimited input field. below code is working fine only the one problem it is adding after the first `<tr>`. it is not adding the field  it after the additional `<tr>`. if  click on `add  option` it is adding `<before>` or after `first`  `<tr>`. ignoring the others `<tr>`.

my html

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" id="orderchecklist_item_grid_servicecenters" class="data border">
    <colgroup><col width="120">
    <col>
    <col width="100">
        <col width="70">
    </colgroup><thead>
        <tr class="headings">
            <th width="80%">Item</th>
                         <td width="10%" class="last"><button style="" onclick="addfield();" class="scalable add" type="button" title="Add Option" id="add_new_option_button"><span><span><span>Add Option</span></span></span></button></td>

          </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="orderchecklist_item_list">

         <tr class="template" id="orderchecklist_item_template1">
            <td><input type="text" value="" name="servicename[]" placeholder="check list item" class="input-text">
            </td>
            <td class="last"><button style="" onclick="removefield(this);" class="scalable deletefield" type="button" title="Delete" id="delete_button"><span><span><span>Delete</span></span></span></button></td>
            </tr>

    </tbody>

    <tfoot id="extra_field" class="no-display template">
        <tr class="template" id="orderchecklist_item_template">
            <td><input type="text" name="item[]" placeholder="check list item" class="input-text"></td>


            <td class="last">   <button style="" onclick="removefield(this);" class="scalable deletefield" type="button" title="Delete" id="delete_button"><span><span><span>Delete</span></span></span></button></td>  
        </tr>


    </tfoot>

 </table>
```

my js code for adding and removing field

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function addfield()
 {
var htm= $('extra_field').innerHTML;
$$('#<?php echo $_block->getHtmlId() ?>_list').last('tr').insert({after:htm});
 }
function removefield(ele)
 { 
var row = ele.parentNode.parentNode;
    row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
 }


 </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just insert before hidden extra field.

**Code**

```
function addfield()
{
  var htm= $('extra_field').innerHTML;
  $('extra_field').insert({before:htm});
}
```

**Another Way**

```
function addfield()
{
  var htm= $('extra_field').innerHTML;
  $$('#orderchecklist_item_list tr').last('tr').insert({after:htm});
}
```

`$$('#orderchecklist_item_list').last('tr')` will find `tr` from `orderchecklist_item_list` elements. So it returns '#orderchecklist_item_list' it self.

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ak4crzwn/)** and **[Fiddle 2](https://jsfiddle.net/ak4crzwn/1/)**

Comment: thanks i didn't think of that way. do you have any idea how to make first  solution work?

Comment: @QaisarSatti added some comments. hope it helps you :D

Comment: so at the end it is simple mistake :D :D